# InkWell widgets require a Material widget ancestor

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am adding InkWell in Row as Widget but it is throwing me an error:

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown building InkWell(gestures: [tap], clipped to BoxShape.rectangle,
flutter: dirty, state: _InkResponseState<InkResponse>#0e6c5):
flutter: No Material widget found.
flutter: InkWell widgets require a Material widget ancestor.
```

Here is my code:

```
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      InkWell(
        onTap: (){
          //Forgot password Tapped
        },
      child: Text(Constants.forgotPassword),),
    ],
),
```

Comment: Material(
              child: InkWell(),
            )  Please try to wrap your Inkwell with the Material widget

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`InkWell` Class will always work with a Material Class

Please try the code below.

Code: Wrap the InkWell Class with the Material Class

```
  Material(
          child: InkWell(
      onTap: (){
        //Forgot password Tapped
      },
    child: Text(Constants.forgotPassword),),
  ),
```

Thanks

Comment: If I did this then my material start showing white background in text.

Comment: Material(

              child: InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            //Forgot password Tapped
          },
        child: Text(Constants.forgotPassword,style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black26),),),
      ),

Comment: Please use the Text style class and change the color of the text

Comment: @CodeHunter  You can use this property in the Material widget
type: MaterialType.transparency,

Answer (score 11):

There are two ways to resolve the above issue.

1. Replace `InkWell` with `GestureDetector`

   ```
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {

    },);
   ```
2. Wrap `InkWell` with `Material`, as `InkWell` required `Material` Widget to wrap

   ```
    InkWell(
      onTap: () {

        },);
   ```

**Note:** To introduce a Material widget, you can either directly include one, or use a widget that contains Material itself, such as a **Card, Dialog, Drawer, or Scaffold.**

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the InkWell Class with Scaffold, then the issue will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

It is not said that the `Material` should be added as father.

If it is a `StatelessWidget` and you **pushed to go to this page**, he automatically expects it to be the parent of the widget, such as a `Scaffold` for example.

It happened to me too, in the end many of the components in Flutter already extend `Material`, so the problem may be sooner.